# Cannot find element in the popup window with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, dom, automation, popup, selenium-webdriver

I'm using InternetExplorerDriver with Selenium Webdriver in Java.

I load a URL which simultaneously opens another window which has the login box. 
Using the method mentioned [here](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/twist/2.3/help/how_do_i_handle_popup_in_selenium2.html)

I could select the required window and also `send keys` into the focussed box.

```
popup.getKeyboard().sendKeys("yeuiryuiryweuiryeuiyterui");
```

However, the following:

```
popup.findElement(By.id("userName")).sendKeys("user")
```

is unable to find the element and throws an `Element-not-found` exception (something similar to this).

Where am I getting it wrong?

Comment: What is getKeyboard() method?

Comment: It's used to send keys to the focused element.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to try with xpath

```
String locator = "//*[@class='Class name of user name text box'and text()='if any']"
```

you can find the user name through firebug

```
List<WebElement> element = Driver.driver.findElements(By.xpath(locator));
```

thn use click functions on web element , do the same on password and then click on login directly using `Driver.selenium.click(xpath);` and provide the  xpath of login button in case id's are not present.